# KIVY Custom Widget pos_hint

Tags: kivy, alignment, android-relativelayout

While using Custom widget only 'x' and 'y' parameters are evaluated in pos_hint parameter. But if I use other keys like center_x, center_y or top the key values are not evaluated. In sample program given below, if I use pos_hint as center_x and center_y the line is not aligned in middle of the layout.
But if i Use x and y parameter alignment works.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.scatterlayout import ScatterLayout


class MyPaintWidget(Scatter):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs) :
        super(MyPaintWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def create_figure(self,  **kwargs):
        self.canvas.add(Line( points=[0, 10, 30, 10]))
        return self

class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = RelativeLayout()

        #self.painter = MyPaintWidget(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.5}) Not working with center_x and center_y alignment
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget(pos_hint={'x': 0.5, 'y':0.5}) #working with x and y parameter

        parent.add_widget(self.painter.create_figure())

        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Even tried with sample KV file as mentioned in comments section

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
<LineRectangle>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .1, .1, 1, .9
        Line:
            width: 2.
            rectangle: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
    Label:
        center: root.center
        text: 'Rectangle'
'''

class LineRectangle(Scatter):
      pass

class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(KV)
        root = RelativeLayout()
        #root.add_widget(LineRectangle(pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}, size_hint=(0.2, 0.2)))
        root.add_widget(LineRectangle(pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}, size_hint=(None, None)))
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Comment: I believe it does work either way. What makes you think that the 'center_x' and 'center_y' are not working?

Comment: When I use center_x and center_y widget is not positioned as per the values in layout i.e if I give center_x and center_y  as  .5 I expected widget in middle of layout

Comment: When I run your code using `center_x` and `center_y`, the widget  is in the center. Try adding temporary `kv` file with a rule to draw a `Rectangle` in the `MyPaintWidget` `canvas` to see this clearly.

Comment: Even tried with sample KV file for Rectangle vertex. No difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pos_hint property allows you to set the position of the widget inside its parent layout, in percent (similar to size_hint).

Comment: Based on sample code that I had give above, if we use 'center_x' and 'center_y' as 0.5, the line will be in middle of the layout. But Line is drawn bottom left as if position is 0,0

Comment: Hope you meant size_hint = (None, None) in python code. With this change center_x and center_y started working. By changing pos = (None, None) got error message "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'". Thanks a lot for the clue. But still I am not able to understand how size_hint helped pos_hint to recognize (or) render as per center_x, center_y keys